# UHD tx_waveforms

Tags: c++, usrp

In the example code provided by ettus research for USRP trasmission waveforms found here:
[tx_waveforms](http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/repository/revisions/d7a353461100be58eb973532ff2c1b7ddaddda52/entry/host/examples/tx_waveforms.cpp)

Line 44:

```
static const size_t wave_table_len = 8192;
```

Is there any specific reason why the value was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is, but I think the folks that wrote that code might be better able to answer that. Perhaps it's tied to the size of a particular hardware buffer, or just intended to be some multiple of the system page size, or a convenient length of time based on a specific sampling rate to produce a reasonable tone without excessive artifacts, or .... many other reasons.

I suppose you could copy the code, change the value, and see if anything breaks...